# Unable to install windows 10 on ZED AIR notebook

Tags: windows, boot, laptop, uefi, windows-installation

I am unable to install Windows 10 on a iLife Zed Air laptop.

I have created Bootbale UEFI USB flash drive and it all goes well until I get this error:

> "smi return code 0xef"

Comment: Have you used the USB before? try making another bootable, may be corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

This error commonly arises when an attempt is made to flash the incorrect BIOS.

Try to update firmware(BIOS) and reinstall again, you’d better ask for help from i-life support.

I can see Firmware download in ZedAir official website

https://www.i-life.us/product/zedair/